# Ho to loop inside another loop in R?

Tags: r

I have several files in one folder `dir`

```
dir<- list.files("C:\\Users\\data", "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
for (files in seq_along(dir)){
F = h5read("dir[files]","var")
cet <-F[,,1]*5 }
```

This loop will read each file in `dir` and compute `cet` for only `F[,,1]` but I have in each file from `F[,,1] to F[,,31] (or could be F[,,28])`

The structure of `F` in this file is:

```
   str(F)
   int [1:360, 1:140, 1:31] 0.2 0.3 0.12
```

in another files it is

```
   str(F)
   int [1:360, 1:140, 1:30] 0.8 0.9 0.13
```

My question is how to tell R to compute `cet` for `F[,,1] ,F[,,2].......... F[,,31] (or could be F[,,28])` for the first file.
Then go to the second file and do the same....

Comment: What is `h5read` related to? We need a bit more in your question to provide us a minimal working example.

Comment: You need to think of how to store the end result. You can do it manually by iterating through the third dimension using a for loop (something like `for(i in 1:n) {F[, , i] * 5}`) but you still need to think of how you will store the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tools)

outputDir <- "C:\\data"
extension <- ".txt"

cet <- list()

dir<- list.files("C:\\Users\\data", "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)

for (files in seq_along(dir)){
    F = h5read("dir[files]","var")

    cet[[length(cet) + 1]] <- list()
    for(j in seq(1,dim(F)[3])) {

        out.file = file.path(outputDir,
                 paste0(basename(file_path_sans_ext(dir[files])),
                 sprintf("%02d",j),
                 extension))
        writeRaster(F[,,j]*5,filename= out.file)
        cet[[length(cet)]][[j]] <-F[,,j]*5
    } 
}
```

Comment: @hyat You want to write every single value in a different file? Every list of value from one file into a different file? Or all of them in the same file? In every case, you could try `paste0(outputFile,j)`

Comment: @hyat see the updated answer. It should work, but I can't test without the data files. You might want to modify the extension and to remove the parts about cet if you don't want the data to be kept in R memory.

Comment: Just because I thought you might not need cet (because you seem to want the values in external files). That way, we can delete `cet <- list()`, `cet[[length(cet) + 1]] <- list()` and `cet[[length(cet)]][[j]] <-F[,,j]*5` and the code will still work. But you are right, if you still want it, this is a good solution too

Comment: @hyat sorry about this, i forgot to add `paste0` inside `file.path` to avoid this. See updated answer. You should update your question with what you added in the comments (how you want to ouput the results in different files), for future reference